# Increasing MongoDB namespace limits

Tags: mongodb, namespaces

I have a MongoDB replica set of 3 instances running and recently I got the following errors in the log file:

```
error: hashtable namespace index max chain reached:1335
warning: hashtable namespace index long chain
ERROR: writer worker caught exception: too many namespaces/collections on: ...
```

This looks to me like the default .ns (namespace file) size limit isn't enough here so I included:

```
nssize = 32
```

to the configuration of each replica set member.

This is supposed to make the namespace files 32MB now instead of default 16MB (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.nsSize).

Questions:

1. How do I rebuild the existing namespace files to have the new limit taken into account? Restarting mongod server didn't seem to work.
2. Is there anything else I should do apart from changing this limit to get rid of such errors?

Comment: I do belive the ns file is allocated upon creation of the database as such you need to recreate the database for it to have an effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I rebuild the existing namespace files to have the new limit taken into account? Restarting mongod server didn't seem to work.

You will need to recreate your database in order for this to take effect until: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-385 is around.

> Is there anything else I should do apart from changing this limit to get rid of such errors?

Not really, other than make it bigger than 32MB?

For reference here is 10gen talking about the error: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/YrPqM85N4Mk and what to do, they essentially come to the same conclusion as you have: watch the number of collections.

Comment: Does recreate means mongodump/mongorestore? Should I do it on all replica set members separately or will they synchronize with primary db? Also will mongod --repair help with this?

Comment: @schedar Yeah, though, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/ can also do it as shown here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-282?focusedCommentId=63059&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-63059

Comment: could you explain more how is "renameCollection() method" supposed to help with these namespaces? I tried that out of curiosity but this affects only one collection from the DB at a time and namespace sizes do not change.

Comment: @schedar with rename you can just move the collections to a new namespace by uisng dot syntax for the collection names as shown in the JIRA, so namespace sizes have not changed in the new database you copied to?

Comment: I got the point now. Calling "renameCollection()" moved the collection to the new database - which has the namespace size bigger (32MB) since it's just created - awesome. I'll try this out on my bigger database (nearly 900GB).

Comment: I have a question on this particular issue, if an NS is size 16MB, then what happens to the extra data that gets inserted?

Comment: @tor9ado I have never actually tried it but I would imagine you would receive an assertion error from MongoDB

Comment: What I am observing is that there is no problem inserting data to collections but when I try to insert into a new collection then I see the collection. In the fact that I restarted mongo with the nssize=64 and it is not working. So I am thinking of doing a CopyDatabase, do you think this is a good idea. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @tor9ado was about to ask clarification. Yes, you need to copy your database for it to be effective, the nssize takes effect on database creation

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am preparing everything to do just that. I also have another query, but this one is related to sharding. Does Sharding avoids the issue of nssize?

Comment: @tor9ado for normal sharding I would say no, but for tag aware sharding there might be something, I cannot quite remember exactly how the config srvs actually work in that case. That is where the nssize info will be for the shard to create and use the database. Since with tag aware sharding you can confine collections to shards it might be possible, but this is all thoeritical, I would personally just say no.